# Does building docker images on different machines prevent sharing the layers?

Tags: docker

If we build an image on machine 1 and tag it as `machine1:latest` and push it to our docker registry then build another image from the same Dockerfile on machine2 and tag it as `machine2:latest` and push it to the registry will the registry use the layers of `machine1:latest`? Or because we built the image on a different machine the layers will be different?

In general what factors will change/affect the layer sharing in docker?

Comment: Dear 5 layer create when you push your image it depends on your confugration too. Please check this article explained layer: https://dzone.com/articles/docker-layers-explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the registry uses the hash to detect the layers and if possible share them if we build on different machines sharing is not possible because each docker daemon generates a different hash and this will prevent sharing of layers.